# Cant Find these three CSS background images

Tags: html, css

The images are located at
http://www.zerply.com/home/

The images at the top left below the Example Account heading and zerp.ly/example. I have been inspecting the CSS of this page for hours now but just cant find these three images.

Thanks

Edit: 
I want these three images. I did use Firebug, i found some sprite images(which didnt contain these images).

Comment: What is so difficult in it ? Use firebug and then inspect the elements you want.

Comment: there is no need to give downvote may be it's newbe in css & css sprites

Comment: I did use firebug, and got the sprite, in which I didnt find these icon images.

Comment: @sandeep Yes, but this isn't a question asking how to achieve what this website has done or how to work with sprite sheets (which would be a relevant question).. All that's being asked is what the location of the image/s they've used is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The images in your screenshot are made up of two parts:

1. [This sprite sheet](http://www.zerply.com/img/zerply-main-sprite.png?1)
2. Setting the `font-family` of each `.action-menu a` to **[Pictos](http://pictos.drewwilson.com/)**.

Each of those three icons are represented by the glyphs `:`, `q` and `N` respectively.

Comment: no, because this doesnt contain the three icons. refer to the image in the question

Comment: ok thanks. I'll see to it and check if it works. Kind of uncommon though, having images as characters.

Comment: Not really, websites like http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface/generator let you use non-websafe fonts in conjunction with smart use of CSS easily nowadays. I think it's actually pretty smart.

Comment: How is it smart embedding a non-web safe font in your website(which has a high file size) just to be able to show a few images in your website?(which would normally be only a few KB's).

Comment: Well, one advantage would be that the icons can be scaled up to any size without loss of quality, whereas you'd either have to make a large set of images and only scale them down (which would end up larger) or make a few different sets of the same images in multiple sizes.